# JavaScript variables do not persist in jQuery event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, scope

For some reason, I'm not understanding the scope of local and global variables with relation to jQuery click handlers. When I click the buttons, I'm getting "undefined", but I expect it to show the category of the button clicked. How do I address this?

I've setup an example to show my confusion. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zvhsqeyn/

Simple html buttons:

```
<button class="hobbies">hobbies</button>
<button class="sledding">sledding</button>
<button class="personal">personal</button>
<button class="food">food</button>
```

Some javascript to handle the event where the buttons are clicked.

```
var GLOBAL_CATEGORIES = ['hobbies', 'sledding'];

$(window).load(function() { 
    var categories = ['personal', 'food'];

    // local categories
    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        $('.' + categories[i]).click(function() {
            alert(categories[i]);
            return false;
        });
    }

    // Global categories
    for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL_CATEGORIES.length; i++) {
        $('.' + GLOBAL_CATEGORIES[i]).click(function() {
            alert(GLOBAL_CATEGORIES[i]);
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Edit:
After taking in the feedback, here is the properly working http://jsfiddle.net/zvhsqeyn/1/

Comment: Try just alerting `i` inside your loop and see what happens. That may give you an idea of what's actually going on.

Comment: Why are you using `$(window).load(function(){...})` instead of jQuery `ready()` or simply `$(function({...}))`?

Comment: @GriffeyDog maybe he wants to wait for the images to finish loading too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the nature of closures.

```
// local categories
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    $('.' + categories[i]).click(function() {
        alert(categories[i]);
        return false;
    });
}
```

You're assigning an anonymous function as the click handler for each of these buttons.  That function has access to the variable `i`, because it's visible in the parent scope.  *However* - by the time you click one of these buttons, your loop has long since finished, and the value of `i` is now equal to categories.length.  There isn't any element there, so your click functions return `undefined`.

In general, it's not safe to rely on the value of index variables when assigning event handlers in a loop.  As a workaround, you can use the jquery $.each function:

```
$.each(categories, function(index, value) {
    // local categories
    $('.' + value).click(function() {
        alert(value);
        return false;
    });
});
```

This works because it creates a separate closure for each click handler function.

Answer (score -2):

This is a very common ish problem and here is the explanation

If we follow the process through what you are doing is adding a click listener to the ith `GLOBAL_CATEGORIES` and then moving on to the next one.  You do this until `i` is too big for the `GLOBAL_CATEGORIES` array.

You have to remember that `i` has only been set once and so now `i` is 1 more than the length of `GLOBAL_CATEGORIES`.  This means that when the alert fires `GLOBAL_CATEGORIES[i]` is undefined because `i` is too big.

A better way to do this is with the jQuery `each` syntax like below

```
$.each(GLOBAL_CATEGORIES, function(i, category) {
    $('.' + category).click(function() {
        alert(category);
        return false;
    });
});
```